# Dotnet Entity Framework Include without a Foreign Key

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entities

I have two models:

Location

- Id
- FacilityMnemonic
- Name

Facility

- Id
- FacilityMnemonic
- Name

Location's FacilityMnemonic can be null. It's possible that the location may have a facility mnemonic that does not have a facility. I need a way to structure these entities so that I can do some form of

```
_context.Locations.Where(CONDITIONS HERE).Include("Facility").ToList();
```

And then be able to package that up in a nice json response for my web API. I cannot use a foreign key, however, because the constraint will fail if there is a mnemonic with no matching facility. Having trouble determining the right way to do this with entity framework. Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Without primary key working with EF is not a good approach even we can not add any data in table without having primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use include without relationship in SQL server.

You can use this instead

```
var list = (from a in _context.Location.Where(CONDITIONS HERE) 
            from b in _context.Facility.Where(CONDITIONS HERE related to Location).DefaultOrEmpty()
            select new Location() {
                Id = a.Id,
                Name = a.Name,
                Facilities = b
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: This won't return a Location with Facility nested though will it?

Comment: "facilities = b" is location's nested facility.